# Get filename from path using XSLT 1.0 (c# .Net Core)

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Please help me. 
How can I get filename using XSLT 1.0 from string like this?

```
filestore:/722601940006/2018/02/09/file.jpg
```

A file can have a different name and extension. A path can have a different depth.

I tried to use regular expression and function tokenize():

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize('$file/@fh:fileRef','.*/(.*?)$')"/>
```

But I found out that .Net Core doesn't support XSLT 2.0

Comment: Semi-OT: Please vote for [XSLT-3.0 support in .NET here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4450357-implement-xslt-3-0-for-net).

Comment: zx485, I voted for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are restricted to XSLT-1.0 a recursive template is necessary. So one XSLT-1.0 solution to avoid waiting for Microsoft to respond would be

```
<xsl:template name="fileName">
  <xsl:param name="str" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(substring-after($str,'/'))">
      <xsl:call-template name="fileName">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring-after($str,'/')" />
      </xsl:call-template>  
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$str" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Calling it with

```
<xsl:call-template name="fileName">
  <xsl:with-param name="str" select="yourFileNameString" />   <!-- insert string here -->
</xsl:call-template>
```

emits the string

```
file.jpg
```